# countdown disappears after its parent div is loaded via .load jquery method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a countdown which is activated after the page is loaded:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      var rem_hour = $("#user-card-second-remaining").attr("rem_hour");
      var rem_min = $("#user-card-second-remaining").attr("rem_min");
      var rem_sec = $("#user-card-second-remaining").attr("rem_sec");
      var currentDate = new Date();
      var targetDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + rem_hour * 60 * 60000 + rem_min*60000 + rem_sec * 1000);

      $("#user-card-second-remaining").countdown(targetDate, function(event) {
          $(this).html(event.strftime('%H:%M:%S'));
      });
  });
```

Every minute, I load a div partially of this page, and #user-card-second-remaining is inside this loaded div.

```
function fn60sec() {
    // runs every 60 sec and runs on init.
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;

    var card = pathname + " #user-card";
    $( "#user-card-wrapper" ).load(card);
}
```

The problem is that when I loaded new #user-card-second-remaining div, countdown event disappears.

It seems, I think, I should refresh dom (not page) such that .countdown method could be bind into fresh #user-card-second-remaining div.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the DOM is updated, all jquery stuff attached to DOM elements are removed.
Well actually, the DOM element with the jquery styff is removed, and replaced with another event, brand new, without jquery stuff.

What you need to do, is add the jquery stuff again after you update the DOM, as you suggested.

```
function fn60sec() {
  // runs every 60 sec and runs on init.
  var pathname = window.location.pathname;

  var card = pathname + " #user-card";
  $( "#user-card-wrapper" ).load(card, function() {

    var rem_hour = $("#user-card-second-remaining").attr("rem_hour");
    var rem_min = $("#user-card-second-remaining").attr("rem_min");
    var rem_sec = $("#user-card-second-remaining").attr("rem_sec");
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var targetDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + rem_hour * 60 * 60000 + rem_min*60000 + rem_sec * 1000);

    $("#user-card-second-remaining").countdown(targetDate, function(event) {
      $(this).html(event.strftime('%H:%M:%S'));
    });
  });
});
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. But I couldn't understand what changed and the problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

What library/plugin is .countdown( from?  You need to look at their documentation for a delegated event overload, or an alternative using an event name so you can use jquery `.on('eventname',`

Usually in this situation you use a pattern

`$('#staticSelector').on('countdown', '#user-card-second-remaining', function() ...`

and this listens on `#staticSelector` for events bubbling up from `'#user-card-second-remaining'`.  So `#staticSelector` needs to be an element that always exists, but the `'#user-card-second-remaining'` can come and go as needed being refreshed inside your div that is being refreshed.

The section here on Direct and delegated events explains this:
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I don't think that `countdown` is an event.

Comment: It is "final countdown".

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Ah he referred to it as an event so it sounded like delegated event issue on a removed/readded element: "when I loaded new #user-card-second-remaining div, countdown event disappears."

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown See this, it is an event, hence why the function handler has an event arg: http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html